Angular cancells requests that last longer than 1s after page refresh
I have an issue that appears recently when refreshing page. After page refresh outgoing requests are cancelled after 1s, if complete under 1s everything works fine. After page loaded requests are not cancelled even if they last more than 1s.
How can i fix it?
I tried different angular options but none of them worked for me. Only adding retry() in error interceptor fixed it but with that i have 2 requests at backend.

do you have some kind of redirect to sso that is happening during navigation to your app?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
